# Azure ImageBuilder image creation fails because it can't find a base image that exists

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-image-builder

This Azure Image Builder command returns this error:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $imageResourceGroup -TemplateFile $templateFilePath -api-version "2019-05-01-preview" -imageTemplateName $imageTemplateName -svclocation $location


Platform Image was not found. location: westus, publisherName: MicrosoftWindowsDesktop, offer: Windows-10, sku: 20h1-evd, version: latest.
```

This is from my template:

```
  "source": {
    "type": "PlatformImage",
    "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop",
    "offer": "Windows-10",
    "sku": "20h1-evd",
    "version": "latest"
  },
```

When I run

```
Get-AzVMImageSku -Location westus -PublisherName MicrosoftWindowsDesktop -Offer Windows-10
```

it returns

```
Skus          Offer      PublisherName           Location Id
----          -----      -------------           -------- --
...
20h1-evd     Windows-10 MicrosoftWindowsDesktop westus   /Subscriptions/68fab0aa-ab1e-4e09-a325-46ec73e30541/Providers/Microsoft.Compute/Locations/westus/Publishers/Mi…
```

A [bug has been opened for several months](https://github.com/Azure/azvmimagebuilder/issues/34).  The work around is to use Windows 2019-Datacenter as the base image.  Is there a way to make image builder work with Windows-10?
It seems like Microsoft just ignores problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing what is available to your region with what is available as an image within the compute gallery (specifically, Azure Image Builder). AIB images run some months behind, and in some cases, simply do not provide the image you want.

Head to this site: https://az-vm-image.info/?cmd=--all which will allow you to filter exactly as you need. You will see that "sku": "20h1-evd" is not an option to AIB.